# Can re-inserting an element "re-validate" iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-set

I have some objects in an `unordered_set` that, at some point, need to be updated in a way that doesn't change the behavior of the hashing function or comparison operator. Splitting up the struct into a map or having a mutable field are not options right now. I've come up with a solution:

```cpp
struct X { int x, y; };
// operator== and hash defined using only x
std::unordered_set<X> mySet;
// insert a bunch of stuff...
mySet.emplace(1, 2); // y contains 2

// get an iterator and a reference to the element
auto it = mySet.find(X{ 1, 3 }); // (y field here doesn't matter)
const X& ref = *it; // get a pointer to the element
std::cout << ref.y << '\n'; // 2
std::cout << it->y << '\n'; // 2

// now i want to change y to 4
mySet.erase(it);
mySet.emplace_hint(it, 1, 4); // y now contains 4
std::cout << ref.y << '\n'; // 4 or UB?
std::cout << it->y << '\n'; // 4 or UB?
```

This compiles and runs just fine with clang, but I'm not sure if the standard allows me to do this since erasing invalidates the iterator where the element was erased. Using insert() with the same value (with or without the iterator hint), is it *guaranteed* that the new element will be stored in the same memory location, thus "re-validating" iterators and references?

Comment: *This compiles and runs just fine with clang* -- With and without optimizations enabled?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Both with and without optimizations works.

Comment: how about giving `X` a `mutable` accessor to its non-hashing parts?

Comment: In C++17 you can use the `extract` mechanism to actually get the node itself out of the container, modify the element, and then put the node back in.

Comment: If the change does not modify the hash, couldn't you use `std::swap` for this?

Comment: If you release a memory block and then immediately ask for a new one of exactly the same size, it is not *unreasonable* for the memory manager to give you the same block back. But there are certainly no guarantees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is undefined behavior, and it's just luck that it works.

Consider what were to happen if the `unordered_set` implementation resizes the container after your `erase` call.

Answer (score 2):

Once an iterator has been invalidated; that's it.  You can't make it magically point to the right thing any more.  What is the right thing?  The thing it was previously pointing at; the thing that is now sitting in the spot of where it was?

If you don't invalidate the iterators; then you never touch undefined behaviour; but using an invalid iterator is UB.